# Adwords API: Can't remove MyBusiness Location extension

Tags: google-ads-api

I'd like to remove a location extension with the following code snippet:

```
FeedOperation feedOperation = new FeedOperation();
feedOperation.setOperand(FeedTemp);
feedOperation.setOperator(Operator.REMOVE);
```

It removes the location feed but leaves a message at the adwords page which says "invalid setting" (Ungültige Einstellung).[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUSyo.png)

When I try to add a new location extension with the API, i get an error that a feed of this placeholder type already exists.
I already tried to remove the link between the location and a campaign with the following code without any success:

```
CampaignFeedOperation campaignFeedOperation = new CampaignFeedOperation();
campaignFeedOperation.setOperand(campaignFeed);
campaignFeedOperation.setOperator(Operator.REMOVE);
```

My only solution is to manually remove the location extension, which isn't doable for more than 100 customers. 
Do you got any suggestion what i miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. 
Prior to removing the feed itself I need to remove the CustomerFeed:

```
CustomerFeedOperation customerFeedOperation = new CustomerFeedOperation();
customerFeedOperation.setOperand(customerFeed);
customerFeedOperation.setOperator(Operator.REMOVE);
```